# How to integrate Google Picker with new Google Identity Services JavaScript library

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-signin, google-api-js-client, google-picker

Because of the known issue described in here (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/troubleshooting) I want to update my application to be using the new gsi sign-in that uses less cookies than the previous versions and therefore *might* have the solution for the mentioned error...

My problem is that there's little to no documentation on how to integrate google picker with the new gsi.

I used to use `gapi` for some picker-related code like even loading the library `gapi.load('picker', () => {})`. The migration doc says to replace the `apis.google.com/js/api.js` with the new gsi url, and a lot of other methods such as `googleAuth.signIn` or `gapi.client.init` are now to be deprecated by 2023. But then:

1. How to load picker without `gapi` available? Or `gapi` still needs to be imported but will not contain any sign-in related methods?
2. How will I pass apiKey and scopes to be able to init googlePicker?
3. For methods such as `GoogleAuth.isSignedIn` docs simply states "Remove. A user's current sign-in status on Google is unavailable. Users must be signed-in to Google for consent and sign-in moments." what does that even mean? I need to check if user is signed in in order to not show again the popup every time they want to upload a file from gPicker...
4. Before, we used to have a `access_token` on the callback of a `reloadAuthResponse` or a `signIn`, now how do we get the token?

Sorry for the question being confusing, I'm very confused with everything. Any input helps, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I came across https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/use-token-model through: [How to use scoped APIs with (GSI) Google Identity Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68815693/how-to-use-scoped-apis-with-gsi-google-identity-services)

I changed our code to load this script: https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client, and then modified the our "authorize" function (see below) to use `window.google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient` instead of `window.gapi.auth2.authorize` to get the `access_token`.

Note that the callback has moved from the second argument of the `window.gapi.auth2.authorize` function to the `callback` property of the first argument of the `window.google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient` function.

After calling `tokenClient.requestAccessToken()` (see below), the callback passed to `window.gapi.auth2.authorize` is called with an object containing `access_token`.

```
const authorize = () =>
-    new Promise(res => window.gapi.auth2.authorize({
-        client_id: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
-        scope: GOOGLE_DRIVE_SCOPE
-    }, res));
+    new Promise(res => {
+        const tokenClient = window.google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
+            client_id: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
+            scope: GOOGLE_DRIVE_SCOPE,
+            callback: res,
+        });
+        tokenClient.requestAccessToken();
+    });
```

The way `access_token` is used was not changed:

```
new window.google.picker.PickerBuilder().setOAuthToken(access_token)
```

Answer (score 2):

@piannone is correct, adding to their answer:

You'll still need to load 'client' code, as you're using authentication. That means you'll still include `https://apis.google.com/js/api.js` in your list of scripts. Only don't load 'auth2'. So, while you won't do:

```
 gapi.load('auth2', onAuthApiLoad);
 gapi.load('picker', onPickerApiLoad);
```

you **will** need to:

```
 gapi.load('client', onAuthApiLoad);
 gapi.load('picker', onPickerApiLoad);
```

(this is instead of directly loading `https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client.js` I guess.)